# Are there any free programs for screen writers

Tags: tools, software, screenwriting

Screenwriting has a very strict format that Microsoft Word cannot fully match. Are there any good screenwriting word processors out there that are free?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yep - [Page 2 Stage](http://www.page2stage.com/) is available for free. You can even download the source code to it. (Disclaimier - I wrote P2S. But it's 100% free with no hooks or anything.)

Comment: ...you're answering yourself? Smells like spam to me.

Comment: Answering himself about *a program he wrote.* Care for some spam, spam, spam, baked beans, and spam with that spam?

Comment: @Lauren, @Ralph - in our FAQ it says that you can advertise your own projects as legitimate answers to legitimate questions *if* you say that you wrote it.  I'd question, though, @David, answering your own question.  The FAQ also says the community doesn't like spam and tends to downvote, btw.

Comment: @justkt I really don't mind a person suggesting their project to a question as long as it's relevant and they say why. But creating a question just to answer with your product seems extra spammy to me.

Comment: I'd have loved this answer if the question was someone else's... It's cool having people writing their own solutions to issues we all face...

Comment: Gee, let people know of something availble for free and get slammed because I created it. If you don't want to use it that's fine, but I'm not trying to sell anything with it, I'm just letting people know it exists as a free resource. Also on StackOverflow answering your own question to get useful info out is encouraged.

Comment: @David - but creating a question to tell someone about your free product and answering with it is definitely not encouraged on *any* SE site, including writers.  You are experiencing the community response.  You'd get it on SO too.  Ask on Meta.SO if you don't agree.

Comment: @justkt - actually it is common practice on StackOverflow. And appreciated as getting the best answer is what matters (at least there).

Comment: @David - [on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16734/people-advertising-their-services-companies) the [contrary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10174/using-so-sf-su-to-promote-your-products), the [community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers/15795#15795) on Meta consistently sees questions where people have been treated negatively for publicizing their own product *in the wrong way*.  Creating a question as pure advertising isn't such a great thing.

Comment: @David - and note [the SE team's response to users they think are astroturfing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/astroturfing-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: The product doesn't seem to be available any more either.

Comment: @paulzag - It's still available but due to the comments above I didn't update the link.

Answer (score 10):

For a non-spam answer:

I highly recommend Celtx. One of my friends and I decided to write short plays last summer and this was the program I used and I loved it. I found it very easy to use and figure out and I had never really written plays before then.  http://www.celtx.com/index.html

Comment: Looking at the website this looks really powerful. And I say that as the person who wrote P2S. So I would definitely encourage people to try this one also.

Comment: 5 years after this answer, celtex is cloud/online only. You can download earlier desktop builds but it is no longer actively supported. As it was built on top of Firefox **and** PDF output requires an internet connection to the celtex servers, people shouldn't use it anymore unless absolutely desparate. Try Fountain or any of the others.

Answer (score 3):

Since no one else has suggested it, I would suggest LaTeX for this.

You probably haven't heard of it.  (Hipster pose; TeX is over 35 years old and is [guaranteed to be bug-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_reward_check), where the current bounty for any bug is [$327.68](http://web.mit.edu/klund/www/urk/texvword.html), that is, 2^15 cents.)

Simply put, LaTeX is a way to create content that allows the writer to forget about format.  This separation of content from presentation helps me focus on the actual creative process itself, rather than worry about how it will look.  There are infinitely many 'looks' LaTeX can take on, and a great many are already made.  For example, there is a ['template' for writing professional-grade screenplays](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/screenplay) ([and another!](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scripttex)).  Here is a link (PDF) to [what becomes of a work written with `screenplay`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/screenplay/test.pdf), and a small inline sample of the finished product:

[image: example output]

LaTeX produces the [most beautiful documents](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase) and is easy to work with and control. Should you *ever* need help, there are mounds of experts in LaTeX.  (If you don't believe me, head on over to [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com).  I can tell you from personal experience that these are the most personable people I've ever encountered on the SE Network, and they are always happy to help you.)

Best of all? LaTeX is *absolutely free*.

---

I feel like I've done a poor job of advertisement, but I would challenge you to look into it and explore for yourself.  TeX.SX is a great place to start (in my biased opinion) - look around for examples of what (La)TeX can do (and for why I keep 'switching' from TeX to LaTeX! XD).

Comment: cf http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4935

Comment: LyX works very well for producing screenplays in LaTeX.

Comment: $2^{15}$ is 32,768. Not 32,716.

Answer (score 3):

Any text editor can be made *completely* functional using a Markdown-like syntax called Fountain (info at fountain.io), which is similar to the formatting standard used here on *Exchange.

The simple markup language was designed by a team including Stu Maschwitz (who made Han Solo step on Jabba's tail in Star Wars for crying out loud) and John August, screenwriter of Go, Big Fish, Charlie’s Angels, Titan A.E., Charlie and Chocolate Factory, Corpse Bride and Frankenweenie.

Long story short, it was designed *by* people in the industry *for* people in the industry. The comparison of the [raw text](http://fountain.io/_downloads/Big%20Fish.fountain) and the resulting [PDF output](http://fountain.io/_downloads/Big%20Fish.pdf) of the screenplay for Big Fish on the Fountain website shows how it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're interested in writing in the "cloud" by using online browser based software, but if you are, here are some of the top free online solutions:

1. http://scripped.com/
2. http://www.scriptbuddy.com/
3. Google "Plotbot" (I'm limited to only two hyperlinks it seems)

The benefits of using online writing tools is that you won't lose your work to computer theft or malfunction...almost every keystroke is automatically saved as you write. The corollary is that you aren't tied to any particular computer...you can login to ANY internet enabled computer to access your screenplays...and some of them (for an extra monthly fee in most cases) will allow you to collaborate in real time with other writers if you grant them access.

Comment: Those look interesting but the first two are not free - there's a monthly charge.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody already suggests but I'm really satisfied with Latex.

It's distraction free, can be used in ANY text editor you want and has the BIG advantage of separating formatting from content. In my case, I just created [my own class](https://github.com/efernandespt/Manuscript) to have the final document formatted as I want.

Another huge advantage is that, since it's plain text, you may threat it as computer code and use repositories to track reviews and share your writing efforts with editors and other writers.

http://github.com is great if you want to write something public, and bitbucket.org offers private hosting if you want to keep it private. It's all a matter to understand how it works.

The big disadvantage is that you will have to spend some time to learn the basics but, in my opinion, it's worth.